# Integrate a React Modal in a non-react website

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to build a modal in react and integrate it into a non-react website. I understand that I might need to export the app as a UMD and include it as an  embed script into the host website.

But how do I interact with the modal within the host website i.e open a modal when a button is clicked and close the modal when a button is clicked within the modal.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

It's unclear what you're trying to do, have react in just some place in an existing website ?
You could just render you react app into a div and have it live there.

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Even though if you plan on doing it this way, vue might be better suited.

**Alternative**

- React would be a bit overkill for such a use case, where vue is suited perfectly for it.
- Otherwise, I'd advise switching the whole web app to react. Depending on what technology it is made with currently, it might not be too difficult!

Comment: I know that react can be mounted into a div in the host website. My question is how do I make the app respond to clicks from within the host website.

Comment: My bad, I see the issue now.
If using ES6 classes you could use the `static` keyword in your component methods to make them available outside of it, then, call your component handlers from somewhere else in the app.